# Class for reading infile

Tags: python, list, class

I want to make a class that imports each separate row in a text file, converts elements to int if possible, and then append those objects to a list.

Also, if the row in the text file is more than 6 words, I want to make it so that the first 2 are kept together in the list.

For example, I import a text file like:

```
Hi my age is 15 16
If you want 13 to add
Please use 0 to add to it
```

Making a list with 3 seperate objects,

```
[
    ['Hi', 'my', 'age' 'is', 15, 16], 
    ['If', 'you', 'want', 13, 'to', 'add'],
    ['Please use', 0, 'to', 'add', 'to', 'it',]
]
```

Being completely new to python, I would love some help, thanks in advance!

Comment: Can you show us what you've got so far?

Answer (score 2):

This can be done very simply using a small loop construct. We can open the file as part of the loop and read line by line. Let's say you have a text file with what you entered above called 'foo.txt'.

```
myList = []
for line in open('foo.txt'):
    l.append(line.rstrip().split(' ')
```

This will create the list within list structure you're looking for. But wait, we're not done! Python parses values read this way as **String** types. As such, if the numbers are read in, **they will actually be put into the list as a string, rather than the int you are looking to have**. To determine if its a number, you can use the *isdigit()* method on string.

```
myList = []
for line in open('foo.txt'):
    temp = line.rstrip().split()
    toAdd = []
    for value in temp:
        if value.isdigit():
            toAdd.append( int(value) )
        else:
            toAdd.append(value)
    myList.append(toAdd)
```

This is by no means the best way to accomplish this problem, merely the first solution that came to mind. Odds are that entire loop can probably be performed as some sort of LC expression if one is willing to think on it.

It also **doesn't** fulfill your last requirement, but I do not think it would be tough to do. I encourage you to try improving on what I've provided. I highly recommend looking at what methods are available to you in the String and List classes in the Python documentation (http://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html and http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#typesseq respectively)

Answer (score 0):

```
raw_data = open('textfile.txt', 'r')

lines = [ele.split() for ele in raw_data]

_list = []
_temp = []

for line in lines:
    for ele in line:
        try:
            _temp.append(int(ele.strip()))
        except:
            _temp.append(ele.strip())


    _list.append(_temp if (len(_temp) <= 6) else ["{0} {1}".format(_temp[0], _temp[1])]+_temp[2:])
    _temp = []

print _list
```

Output

```
[['Hi', 'my', 'age', 'is', 15, 16],
 ['If', 'you', 'want', 13, 'to', 'add'],
 ['Please use', 0, 'to', 'add', 'to', 'it']]
```

Comment: I was curious. More for my own knowledge than anything else, is the try-except method of checking more efficient than calling isdigit() on ele?

Comment: @K.Niemczyk: `isdigit()` is more efficient since there are only a few integers and collecting the exception information is pretty expensive.